# Vuejs from router-view to outside component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass data from a `<router-view>` to an outer component.  I found [an example of passing from child to parent](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201/2), but I am not sure if a `<router-view>` is considered a child.  Is it possible to pass data from within a `<router-view>` to the outer component using this method?

I have a `ChildView`, which I have emit an event to pass a value to the `TopNavSection`.

This is the structure I have:

[image]

I sent the event in `ChildView`:

```
 mounted() {
  this.$emit('update-back-link', "value");
},
```

But my event is not being handled via this code in MainContainer.vue.

```
<top-nav-section @update-back-link="handleBackLinkUpdate"></top-nav-section>

methods: {
  handleBackLinkUpdate: function (value) {
    debugger;
    console.log(value);        
  },
},
```

Please kindly let me know whether I am on the right track as I don't know why the handler is not being triggered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ChildView` component is emitting the `update-back-link` event, not the `TopNavSection` component. But, you have the event handler on the `<top-nav-section>` tag. `TopNavSection` never emits a `update-back-link` event, so its handler is never fired.

You should move the event handler to the tag for the `ChildView` component (which, since you are using `ChildView` as the route component will be `<router-view>`):

```
<router-view @update-back-link="handleBackLinkUpdate"></router-view>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am able to handle the event.